# TVOS: Unable to display a GIF with GIFU framework

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, gif, tvos

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1HthQ2oxUI):
In the beginning, I am not displaying the gif but rather I'm displaying a red UIView square just to test:

[image]

By using this code:

```
import Gifu
import TinyConstraints

class GifViewController: UIViewController {
   
     lazy var loadingGif: UIView = {
         let view = UIView()
         view.backgroundColor = .red
         return view
     }()
 
   override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          setupViews()
      }
    fileprivate func setupViews(){
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(loadingGif)
        loadingGif.centerInSuperview()
        loadingGif.width(300)
        loadingGif.height(300)
     
    }
}
```

After I added the Gif code to replace the red square UIVIEW:

```
import Gifu
import TinyConstraints

class GifViewController: UIViewController {
    /*
     lazy var loadingGif: UIView = {
         let view = UIView()
         view.backgroundColor = .red
         return view
     }()
     **/

    lazy var loadingGif: GIFImageView = {
        let view = GIFImageView()
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.animate(withGIFNamed: "loading")
        return view
    }()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          setupViews()
      }
    fileprivate func setupViews(){
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(loadingGif)
        loadingGif.centerInSuperview()
        loadingGif.width(300)
        loadingGif.height(300)
     
    }
}
```

This is the result:
[image]
As you see, nothing appears and I have no idea why.
This is the "loading.gif" stored in assets:
[image]
I tried with a different GIF and still nothing appears.
**Any tips as to why nothing is appearing?**

Comment: Any update on why GIFU library does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I used another library and it works like a charm:

```
import SwiftGifOrigin

class GifViewController: UIViewController {
  
    lazy var loadingGif: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.loadGif(asset: "cvs_loader")
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }
    fileprivate func setupViews(){
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(loadingGif)
        loadingGif.centerInSuperview()
        loadingGif.width(175)
        loadingGif.height(300)
    }
}
```